# to generate object name dynamically

Tags: jquery, json

im trying to create my object name dynamically. below is code

```
var empdept = 'financialDept';

                var settings = { empdept :[{
                'name'       : 'bob',
                'sname'      : 'the builder',
                'age'        : '8',
                'req'        : 'yes'}]
            };
```

so if i want to show the age like this alert(settings.financialDept.age); is not working, but if i have the above snippet code like this

```
var settings = { 'financialDept' :[{

                'name'       : 'bob',
                'sname'      : 'the builder',
                'age'        : '8',
                'req'        : 'yes'}]
            };
```

and now if i want to show the age like this alert(settings.financialDept.age);. this one works. please really need help to do it dynamically. any help really appreciated. thanks

Comment: Don't generate Object names dynamically. Use an array or store them in a map or something.

Comment: both are financialDept. from what i read and did some research is that the object name should be in a quotation. so in the first instance on my code above, im trying to insert a var variable  instead of string itself. thats why it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var empdept  = 'financialDept';
var settings = {};

settings[emdept] = [{
    'name'       : 'bob',
    'sname'      : 'the builder',
    'age'        : '8',
    'req'        : 'yes'
}];
```

Comment: thanks for your help. your solution is correct but, in order for it to work you need to remove the curly brace after the equal sign ( settings[emdept] = { ) and the last curly brace.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 settings[empDept] = { // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var o={key:value};
```

here only `value` may be a variable, not `key`.

what you can do is this:

```
var empdept = 'financialDept';
var settings = {};
settings[empdept]={name:'bob',sname:'the builder',age:'8',req:'yes'};
alert(settings.financialDept.age);
```

I removed the extra array so you can access the value as you described (not settings.financialDept[0].age as in your example)

Comment: thanks for your help, you solution is also good, but i need to have the arrays for my project. thanks again